# How to log out a value in a redux action

Tags: react-redux

I have this kind of strange situation in this reducer action

```
export const myAction = payload => {
    const x = { type: MY_ACTION, payload }
    console.log('sending action', x.payload)
    return x
}
```

The above example works in that I can log the payload (which is a `navigator.geolocation` position to the console.

But when I want to do any sort of transforms such as stringifing this data, it no longer is possible to log it:

```
export const myAction = payload => {
    const x = { type: MY_ACTION, payload }
    const st = JSON.stringify(x)
    console.log('stringified', st)
    return x
}
```

The above results in `st` being blank and not logged. 
Is there some magic going on here that I don't understand?

Any advice, pointers to docs, etc would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I think this might be a [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If it is the action you want, you can look at [redux devtools](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools)

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the answer was that the `navigator.geolocation` object is not `stringifi-able` ...